# R Multiple Regression - Group Means

Tags: r, linear-regression, r-car

How do I get a group mean holding for all other variables (using multiple regression)? I saw an analysis that did this, and am trying to produce something similar for a different set of data.

For example, using the Prestige dataset from the car pacakge:

```
library(car)
df<-Prestige
df$Group<-ifelse(df$women>.25,"High","Low") #this is a useless variable for regression, but I put this in because the real data i'm working with has multiple categorical variables, which makes it more confusing (I know how to get the means when there are only continuous vars)
reg<-lm(income~education+women+prestige+census+factor(type)+factor(Group),data=df)
summary(reg)
```

gives me the following output

```
Call:
lm(formula = income ~ education + women + prestige + census + 
factor(type) + factor(Group), data = df)

Residuals:
Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-7743.7  -947.9  -331.8   744.8 14307.5 

Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       -33.79732 3056.02530  -0.011 0.991201    
education         130.75186  290.21943   0.451 0.653414    
women             -52.78426   10.00398  -5.276 9.03e-07 ***
prestige          139.42427   36.59482   3.810 0.000254 ***
census              0.04043    0.23694   0.171 0.864892    
factor(type)prof  534.53024 1810.15685   0.295 0.768449    
factor(type)wc    368.17807 1181.93287   0.312 0.756137    
factor(Group)Low  367.09089 1274.25821   0.288 0.773946    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2646 on 90 degrees of freedom
  (4 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.6366,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6084 
F-statistic: 22.53 on 7 and 90 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16Coefficients:
```

I know that 368.17807 is the difference between the means between type==wc and the reference group (type==bc), but how do I get the actual means? This should be DIFFERENT than just calculating the mean of all observations with each type, which can be found by

```
aggregate(income~type,data=df,FUN=mean)
```

Comment: I think linear regression does control all other variables?

Comment: @Cory yes but it only shows the difference between the means! What I want is the actual means

Comment: The predicted values from the model depend on all the other variables you included in the model. So to get predicted means (you can't really get "actual means" from a regression model), you need to decide how to treat all the other variables. Do you want to fix them at their mean?

Comment: @Marius That makes complete sense, it's just that I saw some analysis that appeared to be doing it so I was curious if there was some way I didn't know about. I guess the only solution would be to fix them at their means, then. This gets more complicated with categorical variables though. Would I have to convert my categorical variables to dummy variables and get a 'mean'-esque number for these?

Comment: I've never used means for categorical variables; I've just built tables / data frames for the various combinations of categorical variables in conjunction with the means of the continuous variables. `expand.grid()` has met my needs.

Comment: I like Jason's suggestion. I think there are some ways to approximate a "mean" for categorical variables, but as a starting point just go with the simple approach of getting means for each combination.

Comment: I have never used expand.grid() before so I will have to look into that. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: The  coefficients are the MEAN CHANGE in the response variable based on the specific predictor variable (or category of a variable) in response to a change of 1 in the predictor. So for each category you have an individual mean change based on the influence of that category within the variable on the response variable. There is definitely no way to extract a mean value for the observations themselves.